# tensorflow bazel build failed - no such package '@protobuf//'

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, bazel

Even I installed protobuf (2.6.1) and tested its examples successfully, I got the following error when I built tensorflow (0.9) on ubuntu 14.04. Any idea for this?

```
# bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer
ERROR: /usr/local/tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/BUILD:61:1: error loading package 
'tensorflow/core': Encountered error while reading extension file 'protobuf.bzl': no such package '@protobuf//': Error cloning repository: https://github.com/google/protobuf: cannot open git-upload-pack caused by https://github.com/google/protobuf: cannot open git-upload-pack caused by github.com and referenced by '//tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer'.
    ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer' failed; build aborted.
    INFO: Elapsed time: 20.990s
```

Comment: Which version of Bazel are you using? I had the same error using the latest version 0.3, but it worked with version 0.2.2

Comment: I'm using the version 0.3. I'll test the version 0.2.2. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Avishkar, thhanks fot your help. I pass the problem even though I got another problems related my secured environments.

Comment: @Min Could you share your solution? I have the same problem but have no idea how to solve it. Your solution would be super helpful!